# INSERTAR EN TABLAS RELACIONADAS CON INPUTS Y SELECTS

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3

Hola el problema que tengo es que no puedo insertar  datos en una tabla relacionada estoy usando combos e input estoy teniendo en cuenta que los combos se cargan por base de datos
Aqui esta mi modelo

**usuarios_model**

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Usuarios_model extends CI_Model {

    function guardar($data){

        $this->db->insert("cmi_curs_regi", $data);
        if ($this->db->affected_rows() > 0) {
            return true;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }

    }

    public function get_categorias(){
      $query = $this->db->query('SELECT COD_MODA,NOM_MODA FROM cmi_moda');

    if ($query->num_rows()>0)
        foreach($query->result() as $row){

   $datos[($row->COD_MODA)] = $row->NOM_MODA;


}
        $query->free_result();//libera la memoria despues de usar el foreach cuando se tiene bastante data
        return $datos;



}

    public function get_sujeto(){
      $query = $this->db->query('SELECT COD_SUJE_MEDI,NOM_SUJE_MEDI FROM cmi_suje_medi');

    if ($query->num_rows()>0)
        foreach($query->result() as $row){

   $sujeto[($row->COD_SUJE_MEDI)] = $row->NOM_SUJE_MEDI;


}
        $query->free_result();//libera la memoria despues de usar el foreach cuando se tiene bastante data
        return $sujeto;



}

    public function get_curso(){
      $query = $this->db->query('SELECT COD_TIPO_CURS,NOM_TIPO_CURS FROM cmi_tipo_curs');

    if ($query->num_rows()>0)
        foreach($query->result() as $row){

   $curso[($row->COD_TIPO_CURS)] = $row->NOM_TIPO_CURS;
}
        $query->free_result();//libera la memoria despues de usar el foreach cuando se tiene bastante data
        return $curso;



}



    public function get_nombre_curso(){
      $query = $this->db->query('SELECT COD_CURS,NOM_CURS FROM cmi_curs');

    if ($query->num_rows()>0)
        foreach($query->result() as $row){

   $nombrecurso[($row->COD_CURS)] = $row->NOM_CURS;
}
        $query->free_result();//libera la memoria despues de usar el foreach cuando se tiene bastante data
        return $nombrecurso;



}



    public function get_distribucion(){
      $query = $this->db->query('SELECT COD_DIST_GAST,NOM_DIST_GAST FROM cmi_dist_gast');

    if ($query->num_rows()>0)
        foreach($query->result() as $row){

   $distribucion[($row->COD_DIST_GAST)] = $row->NOM_DIST_GAST;
}
        $query->free_result();//libera la memoria despues de usar el foreach cuando se tiene bastante data
        return $distribucion;



}


    public function get_nivel_med(){
      $query = $this->db->query('SELECT COD_NIVE_MEDI,DES_NIVE_MEDI FROM cmi_nive_medi');

    if ($query->num_rows()>0)
        foreach($query->result() as $row){

   $nivel[($row->COD_NIVE_MEDI)] = $row->DES_NIVE_MEDI ;
}
        $query->free_result();//libera la memoria despues de usar el foreach cuando se tiene bastante data
        return $nivel;



}


    public function get_criterio_eval(){
      $query = $this->db->query('SELECT COD_CRIT_EVAL,NOM_CRIT_EVAL FROM cmi_crit_eval');

    if ($query->num_rows()>0)
        foreach($query->result() as $row){

   $criterio[($row->COD_CRIT_EVAL)] = $row->NOM_CRIT_EVAL;
}
        $query->free_result();//libera la memoria despues de usar el foreach cuando se tiene bastante data
        return $criterio;



}

    public function get_cliente(){
      $query = $this->db->query('SELECT COD_CLIE,NOM_CLIE FROM cmi_clie');

    if ($query->num_rows()>0)
        foreach($query->result() as $row){

   $cliente[($row->COD_CLIE)] = $row->NOM_CLIE;
}
        $query->free_result();//libera la memoria despues de usar el foreach cuando se tiene bastante data
        return $cliente;



}


}
```

**mi controlador usuarios.php**

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Usuarios extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('Usuarios_model');

    }

                    public function index(){

                  $data['datos'] = $this->Usuarios_model->get_categorias();
                  $data['sujeto'] = $this->Usuarios_model->get_sujeto();
                  $data['curso'] = $this->Usuarios_model->get_curso();
                  $data['criterio'] = $this->Usuarios_model->get_criterio_eval();
                  $data['nivel'] = $this->Usuarios_model-> get_nivel_med();
                  $data['nombrecurso'] = $this->Usuarios_model->get_nombre_curso();
                  $data['distribucion'] = $this->Usuarios_model->get_distribucion();
                  $data['cliente']=$this->Usuarios_model->get_cliente();
                  $this->load->view('frontend/usuarios',$data);

                 }


    public function guardar(){
        if ($this->input->is_ajax_request()) {
            $anio = $this->input->post("cboañio");
            $mes = $this->input->post("cbomes");
            $plan = $this->input->post("cboplan");
            $implem = $this->input->post("cboimple");
            $curso = $this->input->post("cbocurso");
            $numcola= $this->input->post("cbonumcola");
            $part = $this->input->post("cbopart");
            $deser = $this->input->post("cbodeser");
            $grupo = $this->input->post("cbogrupo");
            $hora = $this->input->post("cbohora");
            $facili = $this->input->post("cbofacili");
            $tipocurso= $this->input->post("cbotipocurso");

            $this->form_validation->set_rules('cboañio','Año', 'required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('cbomes','Mes', 'required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('cboplan','Plan', 'required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('cboimple','Implementacion', 'required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('cbocurso','Curso', 'required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('cbonumcola', 'Numero', 'required|valid_email');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('cbopart', 'Participantes', 'required|valid_email');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('cbodeser', 'Desertores', 'required|valid_email');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('cbogrupo', 'Grupos', 'required|valid_email');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('cbohora', 'Horario', 'required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('cbofacili', 'Facilitador', 'required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('cbotipocurso', 'TipoCurso', 'required');
            if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE) {
                $data = [

                    "nombre" => $anio,
                    "apellido" =>$mes,
                    "correo" => $plan, 
                    "correo" => $implem, 
                    "correo" => $curso, 
                    "correo" => $numcola, 
                    "correo" => $part, 
                    "correo" => $deser, 
                    "correo" => $grupo, 
                    "correo" => $hora, 
                    "correo" => $facili ,


                ];

                if ($this->Usuarios_model->guardar($data) == true) {
                    echo "Exito";
                }
                else{
                    echo "Error";
                }
            }
            else{
                echo validation_errors("<li>","</li>");
            }


        }
        else{

            show_404(); 
            echo "no se pudo completar la operacion";
        }


    }



}
```

**vista usuarios**

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<title>Proyecto Empresa | Usuarios</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<style type="text/css">
body {
padding-top: 60px;
}
.contenido{
padding: 10px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>


<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
<div class="container">
<div class="navbar-header">
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
<span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
</button>
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#"></a>
</div>
<div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
<li class="active"><a href="<?= base_url('usuarios')?>">Usuarios</a></li>
<li class="dropdown">
<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Operaciones<span class="caret"></span></a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
<li><a href="#">Reportes Mensual</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Reportes Anual</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class="dropdown">
<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Mantenimiento<span class="caret"></span></a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
<li><a  href="#">Usuarios</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Clientes</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#contact">Indicadores</a></li>
<li><a href="#contact">Cuadro de Mando</a></li>
</ul>
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
<li class="dropdown">
<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">

<i class="fa fa-user fa-fw"></i> <?= $this->session->userdata('name')?><b class="caret"></b>
</a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
<li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-user fa-fw"></i>Perfil</a></li>
<li><a href="javascript:void(0)" id="cerrar"><i class="fa fa-sign-out fa-fw"></i> Cerrar Sesion</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
</div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
</div>
</nav>

<div class="container">

<section class="contenido">
<div class="row">



<div class="tab-content">
              <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab3">

                <br>
<div class="row">
<div id="listaEmpleados" class="col-lg-8">

</div>
<div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="panel panel-default">

        <div class="panel-body">

<form id="form-actualizar" class="form-horizontal" action="<?php echo base_url();?>usuarios/guardar" method="POST" role="form" style="padding:0 10px;">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-lg-1">Año:</label>
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                     <select class="form-control" name="cboañio" id="anio">
                        <option value="" selected="" disabled="">Elija una Opcion</option>
                <?php
                    for($anio=(date("Y")+1); 1980<=$anio; $anio--) {
                echo "<option value=&#39;".$anio."&#39;>".$anio."</option>";
                        }
                ?>
            </select> 

                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-1"></div>
                    <label class="col-lg-1">Mes:</label>
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                    <select class="form-control" size="1" name="cbomes" id="horarios">
                        <option value="" selected="" disabled="">Elija una Opcion</option>
                        <option value="Enero">Enero</option>
                        <option value="Febrero">Febrero</option>
                        <option value="Marzo">Marzo</option>
                        <option value="Marzo">Abril</option>
                        <option value="Marzo">Mayo</option>
                        <option value="Marzo">Junio</option>
                        <option value="Marzo">Julio</option>
                        <option value="Enero">Agosto</option>
                        <option value="Febrero">Setiembre</option>
                        <option value="Marzo">Octubre</option>
                        <option value="Marzo">Noviembre</option>
                        <option value="Marzo">Diciembre</option>
                    </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-1"></div>
                    <label class="col-lg-2">Cursos planeados al mes:</label>
                    <div class="col-md-1">

                    <input type="text" name="cboplan" id="nombressele" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-lg-2">Curso Implementacion:</label>
                    <div class="col-md-1">

                    <input type="text" name="cboimple" id="nombressele" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-1"></div>
                    <label class="col-lg-1">Nombre Curso:</label>
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                    <select name="cbocurso" class="form-control">
                        <option value="" selected="" disabled="">Elija una Opcion</option>
                    <?php

                    foreach ($nombrecurso as $nc => $categoria){

                       echo '<option values="',$nc,'">',$categoria,'</option>';
                     }
                     ?>
                    </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-1"></div>
                    <label class="col-lg-2">Numeros de Colaboradores:</label>
                    <div class="col-md-1">

                    <input type="text" name="cbonumcola" id="nombressele" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-lg-2">Participantes:</label>
                    <div class="col-md-1">

                    <input type="text" name="cboparte" id="nombressele" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-1"></div>
                    <label class="col-lg-2">Desercion:</label>
                    <div class="col-md-1">

                    <input type="text" name="cbodeser" id="nombressele" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-1"></div>
                    <label class="col-lg-2">Grupos:</label>
                    <div class="col-md-1">

                    <input type="text" name="cbogrupo" id="nombressele" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-lg-2">Hora Curso:</label>
                    <div class="col-md-1">

                    <input type="text" name="cbohora" id="nombressele" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-1"></div>
                    <label class="col-lg-2">Facilitadores:</label>
                    <div class="col-md-1">

                    <input type="text" name="cbofacili" id="nombressele" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-1"></div>
                    <label class="col-lg-1">Tipo de Curso:</label>
                    <div class="col-md-2">

                    <select name="cbotipocurso" class="form-control">
                        <option value="" selected="" disabled="">Elija una Opcion</option>
                    <?php

                    foreach ($curso as $c => $categoria){

                       echo '<option values="',$c,'">',$categoria,'</option>';
                     }


                    ?>
                    </select>
                    </div>

                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-lg-1">Modalidad:</label>
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                    <select name="Categorias" class="form-control">
                        <option value="" selected="" disabled="">Elija una Opcion</option>
                    <?php

                    foreach ($datos as $i => $categoria){

                       echo '<option values="',$i,'">',$categoria,'</option>';
                     }


                    ?>
                    </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-1"></div>
                    <label class="col-lg-1">Formacion:</label>
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                    <select name="Curso" class="form-control">
                    <option value="" selected="" disabled="">Elija una Opcion</option>
                    <?php

                    foreach ($distribucion as $d => $categoria){

                       echo '<option values="',$d,'">',$categoria,'</option>';
                     }
                     ?>
                    </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-1"></div>
                    <label class="col-lg-2">Presupuesto:</label>
                    <div class="col-md-1">

                    <input type="text" name="nombressele" id="nombressele" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-lg-1">Proyecto al que pertenece:</label>
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                    <select name="Curso" class="form-control">
                        <option value="" selected="" disabled="">Elija una Opcion</option>
                    <?php

                    foreach ($cliente as $ci => $categoria){

                       echo '<option values="',$ci,'">',$categoria,'</option>';
                     }
                     ?>
                    </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-1"></div>
                    <label class="col-lg-2">Responsable:</label>
                    <div class="col-md-1">

                    <input type="text" name="nombressele" id="nombressele" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-1"></div>
                    <label class="col-lg-2">Costo del Curso:</label>
                    <div class="col-md-1">
                    <input type="hidden" id="idsele" name="idsele" value="">
                    <input type="text" name="nombressele" id="nombressele" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-lg-2">Costos D y D:</label>
                    <div class="col-md-1">

                    <input type="text" name="nombressele" id="nombressele" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-1"></div>
                    <label class="col-lg-2">Gasto nominas de la compañia x mes:</label>
                    <div class="col-md-1">

                    <input type="text" name="nombressele" id="nombressele" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-1"></div>
                    <label class="col-lg-1">Sujeto de la medicion:</label>
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                    <select name="Categorias" class="form-control">
                        <option value="" selected="" disabled="">Elija una Opcion</option>
                    <?php

                    foreach ($sujeto as $s => $sujeto){

                       echo '<option values="',$s,'">',$sujeto,'</option>';
                     }


                    ?>
                    </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-lg-1">Nivel de medicion:</label>
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                    <select name="Categorias" class="form-control">
                        <option value="" selected="" disabled="">Elija una Opcion</option>
                    <?php

                    foreach ($nivel as $n => $medicion){

                       echo '<option values="',$n,'">',$medicion,'</option>';
                     }


                    ?>
                    </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-1"></div>
                    <label class="col-lg-1">Contenidos:</label>
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                <select name="Categorias" class="form-control">
                        <option value="" selected="" disabled="">Elija una Opcion</option>
                    <?php

                    foreach ($nivel as $n => $medicion){

                       echo '<option values="',$n,'">',$medicion,'</option>';
                     }


                    ?>
                    </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-1"></div>
                    <label class="col-lg-1">Reaccion:</label>
                    <div class="col-md-2">

                    <select name="Curso" class="form-control">
                        <option value="" selected="" disabled="">Elija una Opcion</option>
                    <?php

                    foreach ($criterio as $ci => $categoria){

                       echo '<option values="',$ci,'">',$categoria,'</option>';
                     }


                    ?>
                    </select>

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-lg-1">Diseño:</label>
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                    <select name="Curso" class="form-control">
                        <option value="" selected="" disabled="">Elija una Opcion</option>
                    <?php

                    foreach ($criterio as $ci => $categoria){

                       echo '<option values="',$ci,'">',$categoria,'</option>';
                     }


                    ?>
                    </select>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-1"></div>
                    <label class="col-lg-1">Facilitador:</label>
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                    <select name="Curso" class="form-control">
                        <option value="" selected="" disabled="">Elija una Opcion</option>
                    <?php

                    foreach ($criterio as $ci => $categoria){

                       echo '<option values="',$ci,'">',$categoria,'</option>';
                     }


                    ?>
                    </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-1"></div>
                    <label class="col-lg-1">Implementacion:</label>

                    <div class="col-md-2">
                    <select name="Curso" class="form-control">
                        <option value="" selected="" disabled="">Elija una Opcion</option>
                    <?php

                    foreach ($criterio as $ci => $categoria){

                       echo '<option values="',$ci,'">',$categoria,'</option>';
                     }


                    ?>
                    </select>
                    </div>

                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-lg-1">Resultado Acumulado:</label>
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                    <select name="Curso" class="form-control">
                        <option value="" selected="" disabled="">Elija una Opcion</option>
                    <?php

                    foreach ($criterio as $ci => $categoria){

                       echo '<option values="',$ci,'">',$categoria,'</option>';
                     }


                    ?>
                    </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-1"></div>
                    <label class="col-lg-2">Nota promedio:</label>
                    <div class="col-md-1">

                    <input type="text" name="nombressele" id="nombressele" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-1"></div>
                    <label class="col-lg-2">Numero de Certificacion:</label>
                    <div class="col-md-1">

                    <input type="text" name="nombressele" id="nombressele" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-lg-2">Numero de aprobados:</label>
                    <div class="col-md-1">

                    <input type="text" name="nombressele" id="nombressele" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-1"></div>
                    <label class="col-lg-2">Numero de sobresalientes:</label>
                    <div class="col-md-1">

                    <input type="text" name="nombressele" id="nombressele" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-1"></div>
                    <label class="col-lg-2">Numero de suficientes:</label>
                    <div class="col-md-1">

                    <input type="text" name="nombressele" id="nombressele" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-lg-2">Numero de Insuficientes:</label>
                    <div class="col-md-1">

                    <input type="text" name="nombressele" id="nombressele" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <button type="submit" id="btnactualizar" class="btn btn-success btn-block">Guardar</button>

                </div>
            </form>

        </div>
    </div>

</div>

</div>

</div>

</div>


</div>

</section>

</div>

<script src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/js/usuarios.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/js/login.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Viendo tu código el error que tienes es:

En ningún lado estas enviando la peticion via ajax por lo que

```
if ($this->input->is_ajax_request()) {

}
```

nunca va a ingresar a la condición del if, podrías cambiarla por

```
if (!$this->input->is_ajax_request()) {

}
```

O en su caso quitar ese if, ya que no estas usando ajax.

También trata de cambiar los nombres de tus etiquetas html que contienen caracteres especiales como ñ, ya que se pueden generar errores por no reconocer esos caracteres especiales.

**EDIT INFORMACIÓN ÚTIL**

Otro error es que estas concatenando mal los strings en los foreach, 
por ejemplo un ciclo foreach actualmente esta así:

```
foreach ($nombrecurso as $nc => $categoria){ 
  echo '<option values="',$nc,'">',$categoria,'</option>'; 
}
```

la concatenación se hace usando punto(.), no coma(,), debería estar así:

```
foreach ($nombrecurso as $nc => $categoria){ 
  echo '<option value="'.$nc.'">'.$categoria.'</option>'; 
}
```

también el atributo value de option esta como values, debe ser value.

Comment: el objetivo es poder grabar en una tabla relacionada,el escenario es que tengo un combo que se cargo desde la base de datos en la vista ; a parte en el controlador tengo esto en su metodo guadar  $curso = $this->input->post("cbocurso");
   var_dump($curso ); exit();  y cuando lo imprimo me trae el nombre y no me trae el value; Como lo podria hacer para que me traiga el value y asi poder insertar

Comment: El error es que estas concatenando mal el estring actualmente esta así: `foreach ($nombrecurso as $nc => $categoria){
     echo '<option values="',$nc,'">',$categoria,'</option>';
 }`, la concatenacion se hace usando punto, no coma, debería ser estar asi: `foreach ($nombrecurso as $nc => $categoria){
echo '<option value="'.$nc.'">'.$categoria.'</option>';
}` tambien el atributo `value` esta como values, debe ser value

Comment: Ahora si funciona como debe ser Gracias